# Python dictionary sorting Anagram of a string

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, anagram

I have the following question and I found this [Permutation of string as substring of another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737407/permutation-of-string-as-substring-of-another), but this is using C++, I am kind of confused applying to python.

> Given two strings s and t, determine whether some anagram of t is a
>   substring of s. For example: if s = "udacity" and t = "ad", then the
>   function returns True. Your function definition should look like:
>   question1(s, t) and return a boolean True or False.

So I answered this question but they want me to use dictionaries instead of sorting string. The reviewer saying that;

> We can first compile a dictionary of counts for t and check with every
>   possible consecutive substring sets in s. If any set is anagram of t,
>   then we return True, else False. Comparing counts of all characters
>   will can be done in constant time since there are only limited amount
>   of characters to check. Looping through all possible consecutive
>   substrings will take worst case O(len(s)). Therefore, the time
>   complexity of this algorithm is O(len(s)). space complexity is O(1)
>   although we are creating a dictionary because we can have at most 26
>   characters and thus it is bounded.

Could you guys please help how I can use dictionaries in my solution.

Here is my solution;

```
# Check if s1 and s2 are anagram to each other
def anagram_check(s1, s2):
    # sorted returns a new list and compare
    return sorted(s1) == sorted(s2)

# Check if anagram of t is a substring of s
def question1(s, t):
    for i in range(len(s) - len(t) + 1):
        if anagram_check(s[i: i+len(t)], t):
            return True
    return False

def main():
    print question1("udacity", "city")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()  

'''
Test Case 1: question1("udacity", "city") -- True
Test Case 2: question1("udacity", "ud") -- True
Test Case 3: question1("udacity", "ljljl") -- False
'''
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Homework is for Home.

Comment: What did the reviewer mean by "We can first compile a dictionary of counts for t"

Comment: @JoeIddon make an array with 26 entries to save the number of letters in t, afterwards do the same for s using a sliding window of size len(t) (so the count doesnt change or one letter is decreased and another one increased when moving forward), comparing the dictionaries is O(1) because the number of entries is constant (26).

Comment: @maraca hat makes sense, had to think about it for a second lol - 26 letters in the alphabet :)

Comment: @maraca thinking, about it, why even store the counts in a `dict`, why not directly compare them to the counts of `s`?

Comment: @JoeIddon because he is looking for substring of size len(t) in s (contiguous), not subsequences. This means we can construct the dictionary for the first t letters in s and then always adjust when moving forward (sliding window).

Comment: @maraca this would still return false for a size not len(t)

Comment: @JoeIddon ehm yes, that's why we only check the substrings of size len(t). example: s = aba, t = aa... would return true if not respecting the substring length.

Comment: @maraca using a dict or just checking the counts of the chars doesn't involve substringing

Comment: @JoeIddon see example added in comment above, that's why you need sliding window, I don't say you have to actually build the substrings, only the counts and then adjust up to 2 letter counts when moving forward.

Comment: @maraca please give one more example so I can see what you mean, giving an example for two strings but one with a ... Doesn't help me understand what you mean :p

Comment: @JoeIddon ignore the dots. s = aba, t = aa or s = abbc and t = abc. Would both return true but should return false.

Comment: @JoeIddon 2nd example: t = a(1), b(1), c(1); build initial dix for s = a(1), b(2), c(0) => no match, move forward s = a(1 - 1 = 0), b(2), c(0 + 1 = 1). again no match.

Comment: @maraca  both of  those examples do fit the question as I see it ...?

Comment: @JoeIddon How? As I already told you: substring is not the same as subsequence. See linked question.

Comment: @maraca finally get what you mean, thanks for your patience :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A pure python solution for getting an object which corresponds to how many of that char in the alphabet is in a string (t)

Using the function `chr()` you can convert an `int` to its corresponding `ascii` value, so you can easily work from `97` to `123` and use `chr()` to get that value of the alphabet.

So if you have a string say:

```
t = "abracadabra"
```

then you can do a `for-loop` like:

```
dt = {}
for c in range(97, 123):
   dt[chr(c)] = t.count(chr(c))
```

this worked for this part of the solution giving back the result of:

```
{'k': 0, 'v': 0, 'a': 5, 'z': 0, 'n': 0, 't': 0, 'm': 0, 'q': 0, 'f': 0, 'x': 0, 'e': 0, 'r': 2, 'b': 2, 'i': 0, 'l': 0, 'h': 0, 'c': 1, 'u': 0, 'j': 0, 'p': 0, 's': 0, 'y': 0, 'o': 0, 'd': 1, 'w': 0, 'g': 0}
```

#### A different solution?

Comments are welcome, but why is storing in a `dict` necessary? using `count()`, can you not simply compare the counts for each char in `t`, to the count of that char in `s`? If the count of that `char` in `t` is greater than in `s` return `False` else `True`.

Something along the lines of:

```
def question1(s, t):
   for c in range(97, 123):
      if t.count(chr(c)) > s.count(chr(c)):
         return False
   return True
```

which gives results:

```
>>> question1("udacity", "city")
True
>>> question1("udacity", "ud")
True
>>> question1("udacity", "ljljl")
False
```

### If a `dict` is necessary...

If it is, then just create two as above and go through each key...

```
def question1(s, t):
   ds = {}
   dt = {}
   for c in range(97, 123):
      ds[chr(c)] = s.count(chr(c))
      dt[chr(c)] = t.count(chr(c))
   for c in range(97, 123):
      if dt[chr(c)] > ds[chr(c)]:
         return False
   return True
```

**Update**

The above answers **ONLY CHECK FOR SUBSEQUENCES NOT SUBSTRING** anagrams. As maraca explained to me in the comments, there is a distinction between the two and your example makes that clear.

Using the sliding window idea (by slicing the string), the code below should work for **substrings**:

```
def question1(s, t):
   dt = {}
   for c in range(97, 123):
      dt[chr(c)] = t.count(chr(c))
   for i in range(len(s) - len(t) + 1):
      contains = True
      for c in range(97, 123):
         if dt[chr(c)] > s[i:i+len(t)].count(chr(c)):
            contains = False
            break
      if contains:
         return True
   return False
```

**The code above does work for ALL cases and utilizes a dictionary to speed up the calculations correctly :)**

Comment: Thank you @Joe Iddon, the solution that I gave was already working but they want me to use dict, it is a requirement for the project.

Comment: Thank you @Joe Iddon, I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for, will it suffice? @cevadcevik

Comment: Yes @Joe Iddon, that's what I need to do, and by the way sorry for late reply. Thank you,

Comment: Accept then? :p

Comment: Just did:). Thank you,

Comment: Hi @Joe Iddon, It looks like it is wrong, Can you please take a look at it. For example, when I question1('udacity', 'ut’). it outputs true but it is supposed to be false.

Comment: Yes @Joe Iddon, sliding window will be better option. I will be waiting. Thank you,

Comment: @cevadcevik the last function definitely works now :) I have tested with all your examples and it gives the expected outputs, also, when writing I see how storing the `chars` of `t` in a `dict` is beneficial as with much longer strings this definitely increases efficiency.

Comment: Okay I see @Joe Iddon, Also we need to set contains = True, before checking condition. What is space complexity of this? isn't that O(1)?

Comment: @cevadcevik I think so, but I don't know much about space complexity. The function should be fast though and not do unnecessary calculations.

Comment: Okay @Joe Iddon, Thank you.

Comment: @cevadcevik upvote? begging for reputation ik but i've put in a lot of effort :p

Comment: Yes Thank you, but How do I do that? @Joe Iddon

Comment: @cevadcevik Select the arrow above the zero next to my answer.

Comment: I did it @Joe Iddon, but I don't see any change

Comment: @cevadcevik Don't worry then, maybe because it is closed i dont know...

Answer (score 0):

```
import collections
print collections.Counter("google")

Counter({'o': 2, 'g': 2, 'e': 1, 'l': 1})
```

Comment: worth noting that counter is a sub-class of dict

Comment: needs to traverse the substring dict and check for counts in superstring dict