# SQL permutation query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a keyword search functionality. i want a sql query to search permutation of words from database.
if i enter "ABC" then it should search ["ABC", "ACB", "BAC", "BCA", "CAB", "CBA"] all of the combination words.

i have checked multiple option where first they creating permutation words then filtering data. but my problem is this when we entering long string eq:- "ABCDEFGIJ" its permutation words count increased to "362880" words.(long sql string taking lot's of time to search)

i need a single/simple/fast query to filter data from database.

let me know if you have any possible solution.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Normalize your data - replace keywords (or add one more field) with their permutation where all symbols are sorted. Then do the same with searching criteria.

Comment: This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22737407/permutation-of-string-as-substring-of-another) could also be helpful.

Comment: @Satishsehgal . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

As written from Akina, do it the way around.

Store your data:

```
------------------------
| Value    |   Sorted  | 
------------------------
| ABCD     | ABCD      |
| DCAB     | ABCD      | 
------------------------
```

And sort your search string and then you need only to search one time. 
Works for words and wildcards a well.

```
-----------------------------
| Value       |   Sorted    | 
-----------------------------
| In the hut  | IN HUT THE  |
| In the dark | IN DARK THE |
| In the zone | IN THE ZONE | 
| In our hut  | IN HUT OUR  | 
-----------------------------
```

Searching for `In the` will search for `IN*THE` and find 3 results

Searching `In hut` will search for `IN*HUT` and find 2 results

Comment: Akina, Thomas,

as per your solution we should store "362880" number of combination for the string "ABCDEFGIJ"?

i think that's not feasible solution.

Comment: You create an additonal column in your database where you store the string A sorted as A'. Then you search for the string S but as S' and you get the same number of matches. as for search all permutations.

Comment: I don't know what you didn't understand. Probably when reading the 2second solution for "last weeks riddler" https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/can-you-find-a-number-worth-its-weight-in-letters/ you get the point