# Recursive algorithm to find all valid words that can be made from given letters (scrabble solver)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, search, recursion, trie

I'm working on a scrabble-like-app. Given up to 15 letters it finds all possible valid words made from that letters. I decided to store dictionary in a Trie structure. My previous code was making possible combinations and then looking in a Trie if they are valid words. To make it faster, i want to implement John Pirie's suggestion [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880559/algorithm-to-get-a-list-of-all-words-that-are-anagrams-of-all-substrings-scrabb?answertab=active#tab-top).

I'm using [fast_trie](https://github.com/tyler/trie) gem. Comes with couple of [useful methods](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fast_trie/frames/Trie).

After many hours of trying to implement John Pirie's solution i can't wrap my head around backtracking part of the code. Recursive algorithms seem to be rarely used in ruby - i'm struggling to find any help.

How to make program to go back to previous node, check if there are possible paths **not taken** before, search them through and go back again?

```
    require 'trie'
    trie = Trie.read("local_copy_of_my_trie")
    input = "helloworld"
    rack = input.chars
    $words = [] # after recursive search it conains all possible words made from input
    start_node = trie.root

    def search_from(node, rack)
      current_node = node
      current_rack = rack
      $words.push(node.full_state) if node.terminal?
      search_from(choose_next_node(current_node, current_rack),    update_rack(current_rack)) # choose next node backtracks if possible
    end

    def choose_next_node(node, rack)
      possible_paths = []
      rack.each { |l| possible_paths.push(l) if $trie.has_children?(node.full_state+l) }
      # must backtrack if there are no possibilities
      # how to mark path as already taken?
      # can i return both node and rack to search_from ?
    end

    def update_rack(rack)
      # how to update rack not knowing the result of choose_next_node here?
    end

  search_from(start_node, rack)
```

Comment: I hope you get some good answers, but consider yourself very lucky if you do. Firstly, those unfamiliar with the `fast-tree` gem are not likely to prepare answers. Those familiar with the gem will recognize that a very substantial investment of time would be required to work up an answer, which will further discourage participation. It might help to remove the requirement that `fast-tree` be used. Good solution that don't use that gem may still provide useful insights to the structure of the required recursion.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Even pointing me in the right direction would be nice. I'm starting to understand recursive functions, but I still don't know how to bring backtracking to life.